# Given $P(D)(x)=\sin(t)$ Prove that the equation has unique periodic solution.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Given $P(D)(x)=\sin(t)$ where $P(\lambda)$ is a real value polynom and it is known that all the roots of the polynom has a negative real part $Re(\lambda_i)<0$.
> Prove that the equation has unique periodic solution.

My try if I understood the questions right.
First solving the homog. part and getting the solution of the form $C_ie^{\lambda_i t}$ and We wish that all the eigenvalues are complex to get homog. solution of the form $\sum_i e^{\alpha t}(c_{1i}\cos(\beta t)+c_{2i}\sin(\beta t))$ and from the undetermined coeff because $\pm i$ is not a root a particular solution is of the form $A\cos(t)+B\sin(t)$ but I don't see how can I say that the solution is periodic if I have a real part which is not zero in the eigenvalues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already at the finish line. Finding that $A\cos(t)+B\sin(t)$ for some $A,B\in \Bbb R$ is a solution already provides the demanded periodic solution. The claim is not that every solution is periodic. Any other solution has a complementary part added to the particular solution, and the complementary solutions are, as you observed, not periodic.

---

You should know that $P(D)[e^{λt}]=P(λ)e^{λt}$. Then you could also obtain the particular and periodic solution from $\sin(t)=Im(e^{it})$ as
$$
y_p(t)=Im\left(\frac{e^{it}}{P(i)}\right)
$$

Comment: So the only periodic solution is when every $C_i=0$ no?

Comment: Yes, I added a sentence that says approximately that.

Comment: Thank you very much ! :)